# Query for the name of a column with a changed value and the new value

Tags: sql

I have a two tables with the exact same columns, one is the newest version of the data and the other is the previous version.  I'm trying to create a report/query to tell me which column changed in the newer version compared to the old version along with the new and old value.  Multiple columns can change values.  The table has a field (last changed date) to tell me which rows have changed but I do not know what changed.

Is there a way to do this?  I feel like I'm missing something that should be obvious.  I'm working on a MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

I envision the output to be something like this:

```
ID       FieldChanged     OldValue    NewValue
1234     Class            88515       88516
5555     Status           A           I
6789     Code             321         322
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from new_data
inner join old_data on new_data.id = old_data.id where (
new_data.column_1 != new_data.column_1 OR
new_data.column_2 != new_data.column_2 OR
--...
new_data.column_N != new_data.column_N OR
)
```

Alternatively, you could query the [system tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260604%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for the column names and build the query from the results.

Comment: Thanks Mr. E.  I tried a similar route but I would like to more clearly show which column changed and the changed values.  This table has 62 columns in it, any of which could change.